# How do i add a div tag every three results of mysqli_fetch_array looped?

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli, fetch

I'm working on an accounts system for a streaming service beta i'm developing, and currently on the main page it displays a list of members, with their streaming status, viewer count, etc.. Although it does this with everything being under each other, I'm using mysqli_fetch_array looped to display the usernames, every three usernames I'd like to echo a  and then end it on the next three.
You can see it's current state at http://live.alydus.net

Here is my code:

```
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $date = $row['username'];
        $user_amount = $user_amount + 1;

    ?>
  DISPLAYING USER INFORMATION AND EVERYTHING HERE, USES $row['username']; TO         DISPLAY USERNAMES AND SUCH

    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

I've found answers that can do this with for each, but i couldn't get any of these answers to work.

I'd highly appreciate anyone's help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increment a counter using `++` and use the modulo operator in PHP which is `%` and returns the rest of an euclidean division:

```
<?php
$counter = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    ++$counter; // increment
    $date = $row['username'];

?>
    DISPLAYING USER INFORMATION AND EVERYTHING HERE, USES $row['username'];
    TO DISPLAY USERNAMES AND SUCH
<?php
    if (0 === $counter % 3) {
    ?>
        Do what you need every three times
    <?php
    } // end if
} // end while
?>
```